# custom header bootstrap accordion

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The below is my simple bootstrap accordion, how do I go about adding a custom header to my accordion.

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
   <div class="panel panel-primary">

<div class="panel-heading header">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#region">
      <div class="sqr pull-left "><span>1</span></div>
      <div class="appTest">Region</div>
     </a>
  </h4>
</div>

<div id="region" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
  <div class="panel-body">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
  </div>
</div>
</div>      
</div>
```

Custom CSS code

```
.sqr {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  padding: 4px;
  @include prefix(border-radius, 5px);
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #5fa3c6;
  font: 12px Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #5fa3c6;
  margin: 0 17px;
}

.appTest {
  padding-top: 4px;
}

.header{
  box-shadow: -10px 10px #CCC;
  padding-left:10px;
}
```

Is it possible to create that effect in css or should we go with two set of images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, use `:before` pseudo-element and `css-transform` property with rotate:

**HTML:**

```
<header>
    Header text.
</header>

<main>
    Your content here. 
</main>
```

**CSS:**

```
header {
    position: relative;
    background: #5fa3c6;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;
}

header:before {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    background: #3b6c8a;
    content: '';
    left: 3px;
    bottom: -7px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

main {
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-left: 1px #5fa3c6 solid;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #ffffff;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ArtemFitiskin/LutJQ/2/

Comment: Can u just explain me on why u used before psuedo class here?

Comment: @theJava safe and popular trick for such situations - using `:before` or `:after`. I don't know why not. It's suitable for me :)

Comment: No my question is what does the before do here. can u give me a basic ex of before

Comment: @theJava look at this article http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/pseudo-element-before-after/

Comment: THanks, there is a small problem. when the accordian is in collapsed state, how can we remove the before psuedo class appied.

Comment: If you want show `:before` only if accordion are open - add custom class for this state like `.header-open` and toggle them. Sure, in CSS  replace `header:before` for something like this `header.header-open:before`.

Comment: Here is a screen shot on how it should look. http://postimg.org/image/j7kkgq9v3 should i play around transform.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52298/discussion-between-thejava-and-artem-fitiskin)